# Receive all information from classes

Tags: c#, class, listbox

I have some code which I'm having problems which and hopefully somebody can assist me, basically I have a 'Player' class such as:

```
        Player JanMccoy = new Player { playerFirstname = "Jan", playerSurname = "Mccoy", playerAge = 23,
        playerCode = "MCC0001"};
```

I have about 10 players, all of which have a unique code to them self, basically this code is stored into a list box with the Name and Surname. How the data gets their isn't important, basically though there are 10 values in the listbox which look like "Jan Mccoy (MCC0001)"

Basically I want to now be able to get the age of the person in the class, I have an event for  a button which when he gets the selected item from the listbox box I store into a string just the playerCode, which this code I need to be able to get the player age

I know this is SQL but I need something basically like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE playerCode = strPlayerCode
```

I however am not using SQL, I need something which can do that in C#

If I need to add anymore detail just ask, tried to explain as good as I can.

If you could point me into right direction also that be great also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `c#` there is `Linq` which works similar to `SQL`

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE playerCode = strPlayerCode
```

would be

```
var players = myListOfPlayers.Where(p => p.playerCode == strPlayerCode);
```

This will return a collection of all the players with that `playercode`

However, since you said the key is unique and you are only returning a single record `FirstOrDefault` will work fine without the need tor the `where` clause. like `SELECT TOP 1 FROM ....`

```
var player = myListOfPlayers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.playerCode == strPlayerCode);
```

Comment: Thanks, NOT got it working just yet, but this has put me in the right direction! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Then I would try LINQ:

```
var player = players.Where(p => p.playerCode == "MCC001").FirstOrDefault();
```